# How to correctly cite a report with apacite?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apacite

I am using `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` to build up my references. I want to cite this [report](https://aodproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/AODP-Got-It-Covered-Insurance-Report-2018.pdf) in my article in APA style but the citation does not seem to come out correctly.

I believe the correct way to cite this report is something like this:

Belsom,   T.,   Kirjanas,   P.,   Nagrawala,   F.,   Hayward,   S.,
    Uhlenbruch,   P.,   & Franklin,   E. (2018).
    *Got   it   covered? Insurance   in   a   changing   climate.
    London*. Retrieved from Asset   Owners   Disclosure   Project   (AODP):
    https://aodproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/AODP-Got-It-Covered-Insurance-Report-2018.pdf

However, when I use my citation

```
@report{Belsom2018,
Address = {London},
Author = {Toby Belsom and Pavel Kirjanas and Felix Nagrawala and Sam Hayward and Peter Uhlenbruch and Emily Franklin},
Date-Added = {2019-07-25 16:16:50 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2019-07-26 10:53:39 +0200},
Publisher = {Asset Owners Disclosure Project (AODP)},
Keywords = {Insurance},
Title = {{Got it covered? Insurance in a changing climate}},
url = {https://aodproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/AODP-Got-It-Covered-Insurance-Report-2018.pdf},
Year = {2018}}
```

it only shows up as this, with the publisher name after the city and not within the *Retrieved from* section:

Belsom,   T.,   Kirjanas,   P.,   Nagrawala,   F.,   Hayward,   S.,   Uhlenbruch,   P.,   & Franklin,   E. (2018). *Got   it   covered? Insurance   in   a   changing   climate.* London: Asset   Owners   Disclosure   Project   (AODP). Retrieved from https://aodproject.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/AODP-Got-It-Covered-Insurance-Report-2018.pdf

I am fairly new to LaTeX and do not want to use any other package like `biblatex` but rather stick to what I have now. Happy about any tipps!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `@report` entry type is not defined by the `apacite` bibliography style. BibTeX treats entries of unrecognized type as having the catch-all entry type `@misc`.

Comment: Okay thank you @Mico, so what would be the right type to achieve the citation the way I need it?

Comment: The `apacite` bibliography style is programmed to prefix the contents of `url` fields (usually a URL string) with the string "Retrieved from". Where did you read that the `apacite` bibliography style should insert "Retrieved from" before the contents of the `publisher` field instead?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a bibliography style that places the "Retrieved from" prefix string (or something equivalent) before the `publisher` field instead of before the `url` field?

Comment: That is the problem, I did not find such a bibliography style. I just saw in the APA guidelines that it is supposed to be like this - but I don't know how to do this in LaTeX!

Comment: Please clarify which version or edition of the APA guidelines you perused to conclude that it was a requirement to place the `Retrieved from" string  before the `publisher` field rather than before the `url` field. The reason I asked is that the `apacite` package and bibliography style claim to fully implement the guidelines of the APA6, i.e., the 6th edition of the APA guidelines.

Comment: I have an internal document from my university but I also found this webpage that states it similarly to what I have (http://www.easybib.com/guides/citation-guides/apa-format/how-to-cite-a-report-apa/)

Comment: Examining the online guide you provided a link to closely, it does not look like they unequivocally claim that their examples fully adhere to the APA guidelines. FWIW, the two or three formatted references that do include URL strings at http://www.easybib.com/guides/citation-guides/apa-format/ show the string "Retrieved from" placed immediately before the URL string -- and nowhere else. I would therefore rely on the routines built into the `apacite` package and bib style.